# I want to use regex in stored procedure

Tags: java, regex, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which prepare run ids with the following format.

> INFYYYYMMDDHH - run id e.g. INF2022051312 - hour  is 12 13rd of May 2022
> It set prefix as

```
c_run_id_prefix       constant varchar2(3) := 'INF'
```

I want to make it more generic where it will allow run ids with prefix likes e.g.
INF2022051312, ABCINF202205312, XYINF2022105312 etc.

Comment: In the stored procedure, It only allows run ids with prefix "INF". as my requirement is, it should allow all types of run ids with prefixes ABCINF----, FDRINF---. basically I want to add regex to allow optional prefixes(ABC,FDR..) with fixed prefixes(INF).

Answer (score -1):

`^(?:ABC|XY)?INF\d{10}$`

`(?:ABC|XY)?` matches the prefixes `ABC` OR `XY` once or 0 times, this can be expanded by adding more `|` and the new prefix within the parentheses

`INF` matches the prefix `INF` once, if this doesnt exist the ID will not match

`\d{10}` matches the 10 digits at the end, this assumes that they are in the valid format of `YYYYMMDDHH`

The expression assumes each ID is in it's own line

[Here are some examples](https://regex101.com/r/Wup12k/1)